# PHP - how to cast multidimensional object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, casting

I am wondering if there is a **built-in** way in PHP to **cast** multidimensional objects to arrays?

The problem is when applying a regular casting on an object, the **first dimension only** is being affected, all other dimensions remind the same.

**Note**: I am interested in **casting only**!

Example:

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->b = 'qwe';
$a->c = new stdClass();
$a->c->d = 'asd';

var_dump((array)$a); // echoes:

array(2) {
  ["b"]=>
  string(3) "qwe"
  ["c"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["d"]=>
    string(3) "asd"
  }
}
```

As you can see only the first dimension was affected, so how to cast multidimensional objects?

Comment: I didn't quite get it. Your code and output seems correct. What exactly you've expected it to do?

Comment: $a->c is still an object. I want it to be array.

Comment: Maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567939/convert-multidimensional-objects-to-array

Comment: I don't think you can do that, at least with `var_dump` or `print_r`.
You could build a `foreach` that echoes your style and forces array casting whenever it finds a property that's an object.

Comment: Guys, please read the question carefully. I asked whether there is a built-in way. No need to provide answers with recursion. It is not built-in.

Comment: It was answered as you requested => "*I don't think you can do that*". As complex your needs grow, better use of built-in functions you may make. There is no magic, as `array_walk_recursive` is a built-in, as exemple, but you have to pass it a callback function anyway.

Comment: This is not possible using casting only.

Comment: There's a pretty simple workaround though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is if it's possible using only a **single built-in** PHP function to recursively **cast** object and children objects as array, **without** even any user-made callback function, the answer is **no**, it can't be done like that.

There are other ways to achieve it, though.

Answer (score 6):

There is no official way to cast a multi-level object to an array but the good news is that there is a hack.

Use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to get a JSON representation of your object then pass the result to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and use `TRUE` as its second argument to get arrays instead of objects.

```
$a = new stdClass();
$a->b = 'qwe';
$a->c = new stdClass();
$a->c->d = 'asd';

print_r(json_decode(json_encode($a), TRUE));
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [b] => qwe
    [c] => Array
        (
            [d] => asd
        )

)
```

The method has some drawbacks (it cannot handle resources, for example) but they are just minor annoyances.

Comment: Ha. Snap! Deleting my almost identical answer :)