# WooCommerce categories loop in WordPress admin panel

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, categories, setting

I'm trying to create a loop through the products categories of WooCommerce in the admin panel of WordPress using the setting API but the following code output is:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress2\wp-includes\general-template.php on line
>   3550

This is the function related to the error in general-template.php.

```
/**
 * Private helper function for checked, selected, and disabled.
 *
 * Compares the first two arguments and if identical marks as $type
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 * @access private
 *
 * @param mixed  $helper  One of the values to compare
 * @param mixed  $current (true) The other value to compare if not just true
 * @param bool   $echo    Whether to echo or just return the string
 * @param string $type    The type of checked|selected|disabled we are doing
 * @return string html attribute or empty string
 */
function __checked_selected_helper( $helper, $current, $echo, $type ) {
    if ( (string) $helper === (string) $current )
        $result = " $type='$type'";
    else
        $result = '';

    if ( $echo )
        echo $result;

    return $result;
}
```

Line 3550 is this one: `if ( (string) $helper === (string) $current )`

I've read many similar questions but I can't find the error, I know that there's something wrong with the arrays of the loop. I've tried to `var_dump()` the variables and it seems that this code will output 2 arrays but I can't isolate the value `["name"]` that I want to use. 
This is the output of the variable `$terms`

```
 array(2) { [0]=> object(WP_Term)#9234 (16) { ["term_id"]=> int(8) ["name"]=> string(6) "mobile" ["slug"]=> string(6) "mobile" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(8) ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(4) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["cat_ID"]=> int(8) ["category_count"]=> int(4) ["category_description"]=> string(0) "" ["cat_name"]=> string(6) "mobile" ["category_nicename"]=> string(6) "mobile" ["category_parent"]=> int(0) } [1]=> object(WP_Term)#9266 (16) { ["term_id"]=> int(9) ["name"]=> string(4) "vino" ["slug"]=> string(4) "vino" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(9) ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" ["cat_ID"]=> int(9) ["category_count"]=> int(1) ["category_description"]=> string(0) "" ["cat_name"]=> string(4) "vino" ["category_nicename"]=> string(4) "vino" ["category_parent"]=> int(0) } }
```

Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
function offwoo_checkbox_field_2_render() {
    $options = get_option( 'offwoo_settings' );
    global $woocommerce;

    $terms = get_categories( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'orderby'   =>'name',
        'parent'  => 0 
    ));

   var_dump($terms);

    foreach ($terms as $term) {
    ?>
    <input type='checkbox' name='offwoo_settings[offwoo_checkbox_field_2]' <?php if(isset($options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2'])) { checked( $options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2'], 1 ); } ?> value='<?php echo $term->name; ?>'>
    <label><?php echo $term->name; ?></label>
    <?php   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add `var_dump($terms);` before `foreach` and share the output with us.

Comment: Ok, I've added the variable informations. Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18106696/1908331) the apply it to your code. I think it will solve your problem. If not please let me know

Comment: Thanks,I've tried the code you suggest but I'm still having the same error. Maybe I made a mistake in the custom loop or using `get_categories()` instead of another function. I'm still thinking of a solution.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and also add the actual content of the `$terms` to your post? I think your problem is with `$term->name`. What line is line 3550?

Comment: Question edited. I also want to add that this is a test site so, the categories that I have added to try this code area two, just to test the functionality, if I add more categories we will have `array(3)` in `var_dump($terms)`.

Comment: OK, now I can see where is the error: `checked( $options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2'], 1 );`. What is inside `$options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2']`? Can you also `var_dump($options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2'])` and share the result?

Comment: Aha, I see. `array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "mobile" }` is the output of `$options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2']`. I expect an array with all the categories that I've set. But the var_dump only print the first one.

Comment: the first parameter of the `checked()` function can not be an array. With your data, you can use `$options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this question also thanks to this other one:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183007/checked-function-on-a-multidimensional-array

In this case the issue, as correctly addessed in the comments above, is that the `checked()` function is set in the wrong way, and can take only one parameter and not an array, so `in_array()` should be added in this situation. In this case the `$term->name` will output multiple values.The other issue is that the name checkbox parameter `$options[off_woo_checkbox_field_2]` is multidimentional so should be added `[]` in other to store the other parameters that the WooCommerce loop creates.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='offwoo_settings[offwoo_checkbox_field_2][]' 
<?php if(isset($options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2'])) { checked( in_array($term->name, $options['offwoo_checkbox_field_2']), true); }?> value='<?php echo $term->name; ?>'>
<label><?php echo $term->name; ?></label>
```