# convert object to array and retrieve in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

I have result like below.

```
   stdClass Object
    (
      [Test_Result] => stdClass Object
        (
          [Test] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (

                        [name] => test1
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (

                        [name] => test2
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (

                        [name] => test3
                    )

                [3] => stdClass Object
                    (

                        [name] => test4
                    )

                [4] => stdClass Object
                    (

                        [name] => test5
                    )

            )

      )

 )
```

I am trying to retrieve name and add them as option values for select tag.

I am expecting like below

```
 <select id="names" name="names" class="required-entry select">
                <option value="" selected="selected">Please select...</option>
                <option value="test1">test1</option>
                <option value="test2">test2</option>
                <option value="test3">test3</option>
                <option value="test4">test4</option>
                <option value="test5">test5</option>
            </select>
```

How can i do it in PHP? Please anyone suggest me, How retrieve each values from the above result?

Comment: What is your expected output and what does it look like?

Comment: you can simply used `(array) $object;` to convert into Cast Array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert multidimensional objects to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567939/convert-multidimensional-objects-to-array)

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: Can u post your std object, without `print_r/var_dump` ?

Comment: without print_r i am not able to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object is `$obj`, you can do it like this:

```
echo '<select id="names" name="names" class="required-entry select">';
echo '<option value="" selected="selected">Please select...</option>';
foreach($obj->Test_Result->Test as $key => $value){
    echo '<option value="'.$value->name.'">'.$value->name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: This works, but you may want to clean up the code.  No reason to use PHP/echos on the surrounding HTML and no need for $key.

Answer (score 2):

$object->Test_Result->Test is an array of objects that just have a name property.  If you just want that name property, run a map on that array to convert that array to just the names.

```
$names = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item->name;
}, $object->Test_Result->Test);
```

Read more on [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) here.

Comment: Try something yourself, if you get stuck, let me know.